# Zoom out of image using type=radio in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I am attempting to have a mutually exclusive zoom-in and zoom-out of images on a page using only CSS and HTML. By mutually exclusive, I mean that if there are two images with one image zoomed in, the zoomed-in image should zoom out if I zoom in on the second image (view code snippet). This functionality works great, except I can no longer zoom out of the image.

How could I fix this?

```css
input[type=radio] {
display: none;
}

.container img {
width: 100%;
transition: transform 0.25s ease;
cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
transform: scale(2.5);
cursor: zoom-out;
}

img {
width: 100px!important;
height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="zooms" id="zoomCheck1">
    <label for="zoomCheck1">
    <img src="https://www.vintagevelo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/DSC_0040-768x512.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="zooms" id="zoomCheck2">
    <label for="zoomCheck2">
    <img src="https://premium-cycling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/FAGGIN-Campione-del-mondo-1980s-frameset-7.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be input element is it OK to use javascript?

Comment: Yes, JS is ok. I am a novice in these languages therefore I resorted to CSS HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery:

```js
jQuery("img").on("click", function() {
  let parent = jQuery(this).parent();
  parent.toggleClass("zoomin", !parent.hasClass("zoomin"));
  parent.siblings().removeClass("zoomin");
});
```

```css
.container
{
 margin: 2em;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

.container.zoomin img {
  transform: scale(2.5);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}

img {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.vintagevelo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/DSC_0040-768x512.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="container">
    <img src="https://premium-cycling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/FAGGIN-Campione-del-mondo-1980s-frameset-7.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues is radio button state is set and on clicking of selected radio button it does not get **deselected**.

If you can use **java script you can handle it with many different ways**. But as you want html and css only , then there is only way i can think of is having a

**Form tag around your radio input and have a reset button.** clicking on Reset will make radio button to move to default deselected state. and your image will zoom out.

Via - Form tag and a reset button

```
<form>
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="zooms" id="zoomCheck1">
    <label for="zoomCheck1">
    <img src="https://www.vintagevelo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/DSC_0040-768x512.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="zooms" id="zoomCheck2">
    <label for="zoomCheck2">
    <img src="https://premium-cycling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/FAGGIN-Campione-del-mondo-1980s-frameset-7.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
  <hr />
  <input style='margin:5%' type='reset' />
</form>
```